# Deducting Amount From Bills with PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql

Hi Guys I have been coding and can't have a good solution to this problem...
Sample:
From BILLING table there is 2 bills that is cost for January 1,500 and February 2,000
From PAYMENT table the client paid 2,000 and this amount should deducting to the Jan BILL and Feb Bill since 2,000 is greater than the amount of January so should be automatically deducting the 500 to the next BILL February or so on. 
Table

**OUT PUT**

```
AMOUNT PAID - 2,000

| MONTH     |   BILL    |    AMT PAID   |   BALANCE   |
-------------------------------------------------------
| January   |   1,500   |    2,000      |     -500    |
| February  |   2,000   |      500      |    1,500    |
```

**QUERY**

```
SQL BILLING
| MONTH | BILL  |
| JAN   | 1500  |
| FEB   | 2000  | 
$query = SELECT MONTH, BILL FROM billing
$amt_paid = 2000;
foreach($query as $row){
   $actual_paid = $amt_paid;
   $actual_bal -= $actual_paid;
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>'.$row->MONTH.'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$row->BILL.'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$actual_paid.'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$actual_bal.'</td>';
}

WRONG RESULT
| MONTH     |   BILL    |    AMT PAID   |   BALANCE   |
-------------------------------------------------------
| January   |   1,500   |    2,000      |     -500    |
| February  |   2,000   |    2,000      |        0    |
```

I want to show a exact amount and balance.
please help, I hope you guess what I mean to say :D

Comment: Is the query block of code actual? Or is it a mock up? - Also, show us what you've tried, your current code doesn't really show much other than displaying the data.

Comment: mock up I guess, the 2,000 should be distributed to each row until it turn to zero.

Answer (score 0):

-- You should have monthIndex or datetime in your table

```
select t0.MONTHNAME, t0.bill, t0.pay, (select sum(bill - pay) from billing t1 where t1.MONTHINDEX <= t0.MONTHINDEX) bal
from billing t0
```